# DDMS won't load (or doesn't parse?) KML file

Tags: android, kml, ddms

I can't get DDMS to load any KML files.

I have a KML file for example with the following in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Placemark>
   <name>Simple placemark</name>
   <description>Attached to the ground. Intelligently places itself
      at the height of the underlying terrain.</description>
   <Point>
     <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
   </Point>
 </Placemark>
</kml>
```

The docs at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html
seem to indicate that I only need to launch my app and fire up DDMS
and load the KML.  That doesn't work.

I even tried the Google Earth solution suggested at the same link.

I'm using SDK 1.5_r2.  I am doing something wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some quirks:

1. You have to specify the namespace as:

   `<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.x">`
2. "Placemark" elements must start with capital letter.
3. "coordinates" and "name" elements must be within a "Placemark" element and start in lowercase.

Your example only needs a different namespace.

Comment: This didn't work for my file generated from Google Location history.

Answer (score 9):

For those coming here from Google, this is the only online KML conversion tool I've found that will turn a regular KML file into one that DDMS will parse:

http://lab.soledadpenades.com/android/kml/

Comment: This didn't work for my file generated from Google Location history.

Answer (score 0):

This example kml file worked for me. 
The trick was using notepad to create it, not wordpad.
Your mileage may vary.

[link text](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/bbe4bf2170e05d74/54a5bb2a3f43686e?lnk=gst&q=kml+file#54a5bb2a3f43686e)

Comment: i haven't checked lately so maybe the implementation has changed since June of 09.. but see the answer marked as answer.